# JSON help in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a Json like this

```
{
  "a" :[
      {
     "a1" : {
          "state" : "co"
            }
      },
     "b1" : {
          "state" : "ma"
      }
      ]
}
```

I want to write a JS function that will randomly choose either a1 or b1 and give the state for it. Thanks!

```
      data = require('../data.json')
      it('should get random', function () {
            random = this.getrandom(Object.keys(data))
            console.log(Object.keys(productDataSet)[random].uri)

        }

        this.getrandom(keys)
       {
           len = keys.length
           var randNum = getRandomArbitrary(0, len);
           return randNum
       }
```

This is a rough logic i tried

Comment: Please show your attempt. Also, it's really painful to change JSON, you should use JS object instead.

Comment: With that rep you already should be aware, that SO is reluctant to answer this kind of questions.

Comment: I had just completed an example for you when I noticed you removed the line about having tried things instead of providing the additional information that was requested. So I have thrown my sample in the garbage and wish you the best.

Comment: I had trashed all my code. I cant find a good one to post here as an example.Let me rewrite and post it here.

Comment: It looks like you should parse the JSON string to an object before trying to access it ..?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your JSON is not valid.

Once you correct it, you can retrieve your array and, using [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random), generate a random index between 0 and your array's size.

And then get that random entry from your array :

```js
let jsonData = `{
 "a": [{
   "a1": {
    "state": "co"
   }
  },
  {
   "b1": {
    "state": "ma"
   }
  }
 ]
}`;

let yourObject = JSON.parse(jsonData);
let yourArray = yourObject.a;

function random(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

let randomIndex = random(yourArray.length);

console.log("Random value : ", yourArray[randomIndex]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple implementation:

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getRandomElement(arr) {
  return arr[getRandomInt(0, arr.length - 1)]
}

var obj = {
  "a": [{
      "a1": {
        "state": "co"
      }
    },
    {
      "b1": {
        "state": "ma"
      }
    }
  ]
};

console.log(getRandomElement(obj.a));
```